# XML based on input in PHP form

Tags: php, xml, forms

I am placing attributes inside an XML element based on user input on a form. The try is throwing a Hierarchy Request Error. I don't see the error. Am I doing this incorrect? I am not a daily programmer.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['ok'])) {
try {
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$xml->load("PhoneBook.xml");
$xmlYealink = $xml->getElementsByTagName("YealinkIPPhoneBook")->item(0);

$xml_Menu = $xml->createElement("Menu");
$xml_Menu->setAttribute("Name", "Drivers");

$xml_Unit = $xml->createElement("Unit");
$xml_Unit->setAttribute("Name", $_REQUEST['name']);
$xml_Unit->setAttribute("Phone3", $_REQUEST['phone3']);
$xml_Unit->setAttribute("Phone2", $_REQUEST['phone2']);
$xml_Unit->setAttribute("Phone1", $_REQUEST['phone1']);


$xml_Unit->appendChild($xml_Unit);
$xml_Menu->appendChild($xml_Menu);



$xml->save("PhoneBook.xml");
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
?> 

<form method="post">
<label for="name">Name</label> <input type="text" name="name" /> </br>
<label for="phone3">Extension</label> <input type="text" name="phone3" /> </br> 
<label for="phone2">Direct</label> <input type="text"name="phone2" /> </br> 
<label for="phone1">Cellular</label> <input type="text" name="phone1" /> </br> 
<input type="submit" name="ok" value="Submit Entry">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sources used: 
https://www.youtube....h?v=5goNnVNmubQ
http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Revised and removed one of the appends:
`$xml_Unit->appendChild($xml_Unit);
$xml_Menu->appendChild($xml_Menu);`
Now reads
`$xml_Menu->appendChild($xml_Unit);`
No more error, but nothing added to the XML. All permissions set properly.